# How do I set the AuditLog.CustomData field?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm using aspnet boilerplate and I've successfully trimmed down exactly which methods are/are not logged, by using the `[DisableAuditing]` and `[Audited]` attributes.  So that part is working great, and I'm satisfied with my logging levels.  However, I don't understand how to effectively use the CustomData field.  I'd like to use this field to save certain additional data that is not captured by default, but I don't understand how to set it, or where.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: hi, have you managed to pass the message to custome data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `AuditingStore` and set `CustomData` to your data:

```cs
public class MyAuditingStore : AuditingStore
{
    public MyAuditingStore(IRepository<AuditLog, long> auditLogRepository)
        : base(auditLogRepository)
    {
    }

    public override Task SaveAsync(AuditInfo auditInfo)
    {
        auditInfo.CustomData = "certain additional data that is not captured by default";
        return base.SaveAsync(auditInfo);
    }
}
```

Then replace `IAuditingStore` in your module:

```cs
// using Abp.Configuration.Startup;

public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.ReplaceService<IAuditingStore, MyAuditingStore>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution and it answers my original question.  However, as a followup question, is there any way to pass a custom "message" to the CustomData field?  With the proposed solution, I can only create a message using fields the AuditInfo already has.

Comment: I just want to know if there is any way to pass a string to the SaveAsync method that I can put in the CustomData field, besides what is already available in the AuditInfo object.  Can I extend AuditInfo to have more attributes?

Comment: No, unless you rewrite the Auditing logic. But you can inject services into `AuditingStore` to retrieve other information.