# ASPNET Boilerplate, extending audit log

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to extend the `AuditLog` entity in **ASPNETBOILETPLATE** framework in order to add some new properties to it. I have tried to extend the `AuditLog` class (`ExtendedAuditInfo`) and implement a customised version of `AuditStore` Class (`ExtendedAuditStore`). However, I am not able to inject my new `ExtendedAuditInfo` in the constructor and receive two error messages regarding unmatching input parameters in the `Constructor` and `SaveAsync` method.

Class **ExtendedAuditInfo**:

```
public class ExtendedAuditInfo : AuditInfo
{
    // Some properties
}
```

Class **ExtendedAuditStore**:

```
public class ExtendedAuditStore : AuditingStore
{
    public ExtendedAuditStore(IRepository<ExtendedAuditInfo, long> auditLogRepository)
        : base(auditLogRepository)
    {
    }

    public override Task SaveAsync(ExtendedAuditInfo auditInfo)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(auditInfo.Parameters) && auditInfo.Parameters != "{}")
        {
            var parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuditParameterInput>(auditInfo.Parameters);
            if (parameters != null)
                auditInfo.CustomData = parameters.Input.Id.ToString();
        }

        return base.SaveAsync(auditInfo);
    }
}
```

The errors are:

> cannot convert from 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository<SixB.Serafina.Auditing.ExtendedAuditInfo, long>' to 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository<Abp.Auditing.AuditLog, long>'

and

> no suitable method found to override

The procedure above is based on the idea that I found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49577199/7855321)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution based on the official document of [How To Extend Existing Entities](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-mvc/latest/Extending-Existing-Entities).

In order to extend the `AuditLog` class, inheritance must be used. Therefore a new class, let's say `ExtendedAuditInfo` needs to be inherited from `AuditLog`.

```
public class ExtendedAuditLog : AuditLog
    {
        public ExtendedAuditLog()
        {

        }

        public ExtendedAuditLog(AuditInfo auditInfo)
        {
            this.BrowserInfo = auditInfo.BrowserInfo;
            this.ClientIpAddress = auditInfo.ClientIpAddress;
            this.ClientName = auditInfo.ClientName;
            this.CustomData = auditInfo.CustomData;
            this.Exception = auditInfo.Exception?.Message.ToString() + "";
            this.ExecutionDuration = auditInfo.ExecutionDuration;
            this.ExecutionTime = auditInfo.ExecutionTime;
            this.ImpersonatorTenantId = auditInfo.ImpersonatorTenantId;
            this.ImpersonatorUserId = auditInfo.ImpersonatorUserId;
            this.MethodName = auditInfo.MethodName;
            this.Parameters = auditInfo.Parameters;
            this.ReturnValue = auditInfo.ReturnValue;
            this.ServiceName = auditInfo.ServiceName;
            this.TenantId = auditInfo.TenantId;
            this.UserId = auditInfo.UserId;
        }

        //new properties
    }
```

This class has to be added to the context and obviously, a new migration needs to be run in order to add the new properties.

```
public class ProjectDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, ProjectDbContext >
{
    /* Define a DbSet for each entity of the application */
    
    public SerafinaDbContext(DbContextOptions<SerafinaDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<County> Counties { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<OrganisationType> OrganisationTypes { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<ExtendedAuditLog> ExtendedAuditLogs { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, in the **ExtendedAuditStore** class, `IRepository<ExtendedAuditLog, long> _extendedAuditLogRepository` has to be injected as a second parameter of the constructor and can be used to insert the extended entity.

```
public class ExtendedAuditStore : AuditingStore
{
    IRepository<ExtendedAuditLog, long> _extendedAuditLogRepository;

    public ExtendedAuditStore(
        IRepository<AuditLog, long> auditLogRepository,
        IRepository<ExtendedAuditLog, long> extendedAuditLogRepository
        )
        : base(auditLogRepository)
    {
        _extendedAuditLogRepository = extendedAuditLogRepository;
    }

    public override async Task SaveAsync(AuditInfo auditInfo)
    {
        if (auditInfo.Exception != null)
            await base.SaveAsync(auditInfo);

        var auditLog = new ExtendedAuditLog(auditInfo);
        //new properties can be set here
        await _extendedAuditLogRepository.InsertAsync(auditLog);
    }
}
```

Also, instead of inheriting from AuditingStore, a new implementation for IAuditingStore can be created and injected into application services.

**UPDATE:**

Finally, all you need is to replace the default `AuditingStore` in `StartUp` class:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IAuditingStore, ExtendedAuditStore>();
}
```

Comment: Mahyar and @Majid, but how the ExtendedAuditStore is launched ? how or where do we replace AuditingStore by ExtendedAuditStore ?

Comment: I've updated the code. using the added code, you are able to replace the default AuditingStore.